# Copying feature class within the same geodatabase using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, esri-geodatabase, copy

I'm trying to copy/clone a feature class within the same file gdb using C#.
I've figured out that this won't work with IDataset or IFeatureDataset.
So far I only found IGeoDBDataTransfer.Transfer but this is for copying between different workspaces.

[Copying and pasting geodatabase datasets ArcObjects 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000001wz000000.htm)

I know I could do the whole things with a featureBuffer, but that's a very long winded way. And I don't want to use geoprocessing like CopyFeatures.

Do you have an idea how to get around this?

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=208152

Comment: If you do it manually esri automatically appends an _1 to the table names. two tables can't live in the same schema with the same name.